# Unable to execute flutter doctor command

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to explore flutter and followed [this link](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos) for installation steps. I added the path and checked it with `echo $PATH`and I see the flutter files in that path. After I execute `flutter doctor` in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I executed `flutter doctor` inside flutter's image folder / working directory only. I googled for the error and I tried the following:

1. `brew upgrade bash`
2. `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dyli`
3. `brew link readline --force`

but I still face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and I got the result:

1. MacMini3:flutter deepakt$ brew install bash

Updating Homebrew...
Warning: bash 5.0.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link bash` to link this version.

2. MacMini3:flutter deepakt$ brew link bash

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.0... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/bash
Target /usr/local/bin/bash
is a symlink belonging to bash. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink bash

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite bash

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run bash

3. MacMini3:flutter deepakt$ brew unlink bash

Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.0... 0 symlinks removed
MSCOE-MacMini3:flutter deepakt$ brew link --overwrite bash
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.0... 67 symlinks created

4. `MacMini3:flutter deepakt$ flutter doctor`

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):